# Calling function twice override the first value C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to multiply arrays ,

the function *mul*  is matrix multiplication:

```
    typedef int array2d [3][3];

    array2d arr,A,B,C,D,r,s,k;

    array2d* mul(array2d r,array2d s)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            arr[i][j]=0;
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
              arr[i][j]+=(r[i][k] * s[k][j])%31;
                                }
                             }
                          }
    return &arr; 
}
```

in the *main* function I enter A, B C and D values, then I call *mul*:

```
  array2d *a1;
    a1 = mul(A,B);

array2d *a2;
    a2 = mul(C,D);
```

Calling first function will return correct values of a1.

But once calling the second function
, a1 will have the same value of a2.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Post a complete example please

Comment: @student You're returning a pointer to a local variable. Don't. Or your function changes a global variable and then returns a pointer to it (now that I've re-read the (badly indented) code). Don't do that either. In fact there's very little reason to deal with pointers at all in C++.

Comment: `array2d arr = {};` This will initialize all the elements to 0 and make your for loop easier to understand.

Comment: Using array typedefs is a bit dodgy; the code is still subject to the array-pointer conversion and the type adjustment in function parameters , but it is even less obvious without the array declarators present. My advice would be to use `struct Arr { int data[3][3]; };` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit: this doesn't work - below is one that does)
Better solution is this; perform the computation on a local variable (not a global one) and then return a copy - not pointer - to it:

```
array2d mul(array2d r,array2d s) {
    array2d arr;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            arr[i][j]=0;
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
                  arr[i][j]+=(r[i][k] * s[k][j])%31;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

EDIT:
In C it is impossible to return an array from a function. So one possibility is to pass the location where the `mul` function is to store its results explicitly, like so:

```
void mul(array2d* arr, array2d r,array2d s)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            (*arr)[i][j]=0;
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
                (*arr)[i][j]+=(r[i][k] * s[k][j])%31;
        }
    }
}
```

and invoke it like this:

```
array2d   a1, a2, r;

mul(&r, a1, a2);
```

Now `r` holds the results of the multiplication of `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and the following error appears: ‘mul’ declared as function returning an array
 array2d mul(array2d r,array2d s)
                                ^
testop.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testop.cpp:80:14: error: ‘mul’ was not declared in this scope
  a1 = mul(A,B);

Comment: Indeed, sorry. You can't return arrays from functions. I've rewritten the `mul` function such that you pass the location where to store the result. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but where is the edit part.

Comment: I was still typing and typesetting it ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You are returning a pointer to the global `arr`, so the second call overwrites the values you set in the first. Try this:

```
void mul(const array2d ar1, const array2d ar2, array2d retArr) 
{
    // perform calc
}
```

Comment: unchanged arrays should be const &. Moreover in case of this question, ar1, ar2 are just pointers so passing them through reference is just pointless

Comment: If you wanted to change _where_ the pointer was pointing to, it would need to be a reference.  Since we're only changing the values that the int** points to, no reference is required.